# Import 100 images from folder into SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have folder in D:\img with 100 images named 1.jpg ,2.jpg , .... , 100.jpg
How can I insert all of them into a SQL Server table

My table in SQL Server:

```
create table capital_image
(
    id  int  identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    capital_img varbinary(MAX)  
)
```

To insert one image I used this command its work I can copy the command for more than one image, but it doesn't make sense to copy the command 100 times

```
INSERT INTO capital_image (capital_img)
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'D:\img\1.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) IMG_DATA;
```

How to insert all the 100 images from that folder into the SQL Server table?

Comment: Use a loop to generate the `insert`s and then execute the result. Also, it may be more efficient to just store a reference to the images in your database rather than the actual image.

Comment: Are you sure you want to store files in the database?  Why not rename the file(s) with a GUID and put the GUID in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
DECLARE @i int = 1

WHILE @i<=100
BEGIN
INSERT INTO capital_image(capital_img)
SELECT *
FROM   OPENROWSET(BULK N'D:\img\'+ cast(@i as varchar) + '.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) IMG_DATA
SET @i = @i+1
END
```

However, it is more efficient to store just the paths to the images in strings and access those paths from your application.

My test:
https://rextester.com/EHOL25072

In my test I don't insert or get images, I just see if the path is correct.

Comment: I corrected the code in my answer, can you please try now?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use dynamic SQL for this, eg:

```
DECLARE @i int = 1

WHILE @i<=100
BEGIN
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = concat('
INSERT INTO capital_image(capital_img)
SELECT *
FROM   OPENROWSET(BULK N''c:\temp\',cast(@i as varchar), '.jpg'', SINGLE_BLOB) IMG_DATA'
)
--print @sql
exec (@sql)
SET @i = @i+1
END
```

Comment: Hey David Browne thanks a lot. Your suggestion worked